# show diff on word documents

Tags: version-control, ms-word, google-drive-api

I'm designing **a web application** that will enable users to upload `docx` documents and will the show the diff between each revision.

I don't know how to approach the problem. Is it a bitmap, how do I decode the doc to show changes. Do Microsoft has an API I can use to simply send 2 word docs, and it will return the changes between the two?

I also have the same question on google docs. I think with `google drive` it's simpler. Saw this [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list)

If anyone has done something similar or has an example to some similar app, I would be grateful.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at Word's Compare tool? See under Review|Compare. Word's API also support the compare tool's automation (e.g. via VBA).

To use Word's API, you'll need to automate Word. For the details of the method, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128820(v=office.14).aspx

See also: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Compare-Two-Word-Documents-043b2e1d

Comment: can you provide links? I know the tool that allows you to compare inside the word's desktop application, but i'm trying to present the information in my web application

Comment: To use Word's API, you'll need to automate Word. For the details of the method, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128820(v=office.14).aspx . See also https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Compare-Two-Word-Documents-043b2e1d

Comment: thanks, add your links to the response and i'll accept